# ASCII encoding and UNICODE encoding

Tags: encoding

I wrote some korean text and save as ASCII encoding then I can see some strange words because ASCII doesn't support Korean, However if I save this file as UNICODE encoding , It also come up with strange words... can anyone explain why?

Comment: You should add some information about _how_ you wrote that text. A code snippet or something like that.

Comment: sorry for my poor english.... I was meaning just simple text editor

Comment: Which editor are you using? Could copy&paste that _strange_ output here? At least some parts?

Comment: This does not seem to be about programming at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you saved Korean text in ASCII encoding and then saved the same file again in UNICODE, then you just saved ASCII characters in UNICODE, not Korean characters. You must copy the original Korean encoded text and save it in UNICODE.

You have to understand what is going on behind the scenes. I found a great article, although it might be overkill for you, that explains what happens behind the scenes.

[What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encoding And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

If you're not a programmer, you still could learn something from this article. 
It mentions the general problem behind the issue that you're probably having, assuming when you say "strange words" you actually mean "strange characters."

If you are seeing something like this: 
ÉGÉìÉRÅ[ÉfÉBÉìÉOÇÕìÔÇµÇ≠Ç»Ç¢

then this article might be what you need to understand why this is happening and it is most likely an encoding issue.